API Pagination - Want to get the page from the URL and not from the Body
I am new to the API world and have a question. I am currently making an API custom connector call to plytix with Matillion Data Loader. The call works fine until I want to bring in all the records with pagination.  The pagination method I am using is Script Paging. However, I have a problem. The API requires the page and page size to be in the body of the API call.
I am trying to include the page and page size as params in the URL, but the pagination will not work unless I put it in the body.
I tried defining the params in my URI. The resulting URI is:
https://pim.plytix.com/api/v1/products/search?page=3&pageSize=100
But since the page and page size are not in the body, the API will return page 1 with a page size of 25 (the default amount per the API documentation). Is there a way for me to get the API pagination to work in the URI or is there a way to do this dynamically in the body of the API. Any help is much appreciated. This would only work if I indicated the page and page size in the body. As an example, the body of the API that actually works is:
"pagination": {
"order": "sku",
"page": 3,
"page_size": 100}
In any case, I would have to make the above body dynamic with the page number.
As a reference, this is the custom script I am using in Matillion:
@request.uri.set("https://pim.plytix.com/api/v1/products/search?page=3&pageSize=100");
var currentPage = @response.body.get("/data/pagination/page");
var nextPage = currentPage + 1;
@request.query.put("page", nextPage);
@request.query.put("page_size", "100");
var pageNumber = @response.body.get("/pagination/page");
@pager.stop(pageNumber == 5);

Your script looks correct. The script paging feature is not possible in Matillion Data Loader, but it is possible using the Data Productivity Cloud, if you wish to take a look, you can arrange a demo via https://www.matillion.com/data-productivity-cloud
Kind regards, Joe
